# MySQL query (WHERE meta_key and value)

Tags: php, mysql

hello I'm doing a mysql query, which filter data by, country, year. Well, I'm joining the table items, with the meta_items table

**Query**

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.title
     , i.permalink
    , i.description
    , i.type 
  FROM items i
     , meta_items mi 
 WHERE ((mi.meta_key = 'country' AND mi.meta_value = 'japan')  
     or (mi.meta_key = 'year' AND mi.meta_value = '2017')) 
   AND i.id = mi.item_id 
 GROUP 
    BY i.id 
 ORDER 
    BY i.time DESC
```

The problem is that the query does not show data as filtered.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: "The problem is that the query does not show data as filtered" Nice problem how can we help you without knowing the table table and expected results? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I think it works. Here is my pseudo schema:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id int,
    title varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE items_meta (
    id int,
    item_id int,
    meta_key varchar(255),
    meta_value varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES (1, 'Kebab');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (2, 'Sushi');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (3, 'Rolls Royce');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (4, 'Pizza');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (5, 'iPhone X');
INSERT INTO items VALUES (6, 'Selfie Stick');

INSERT INTO items_meta VALUES (1, 1, 'country', 'Turkey');
INSERT INTO items_meta VALUES (2, 2, 'country', 'Japan');
INSERT INTO items_meta VALUES (3, 3, 'country', 'England');
INSERT INTO items_meta VALUES (4, 4, 'country', 'Italy');
INSERT INTO items_meta VALUES (5, 5, 'year', '2017');
INSERT INTO items_meta VALUES (5, 5, 'year', '2014');
```

...which is followed by an SQL Query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title 
FROM items i, items_meta mi 
WHERE (
    (mi.meta_key = 'country' AND mi.meta_value = 'japan')  or 
    (mi.meta_key = 'year' AND mi.meta_value = '2017')
) AND 
i.id = mi.item_id 
GROUP BY i.id
```

The above query brings the result and I think it filters the data as you expected it to:

```
+----+----------+
| id |  title   |
+----+----------+
|  2 | Sushi    |
|  5 | iPhone x |
+----+----------+
```

You can find the SQL Fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c46b0/1